# Internal error: MongooseError: Operation `posts.insertOne()` buffering timed out after 10000ms

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose, next.js, app-router

Trying to post data to Posts model when post button click but getting error :
Internal error: MongooseError: Operation `posts.insertOne()` buffering timed out after 10000ms

I am using local mongodb and nextjs 14 with app router.
I have also tried  { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true } but didn't worked.

Here's the code :

mongodb.js

```
import mongoose from "mongoose";

const connect = async () => {
    if (mongoose.connections[0].readyState) return;
    try {
        await mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGODB_URI);
        mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;
        console.log("Mongo Connection successfully established.");
    } catch (error) {
        throw new Error("Error connecting to Mongoose");
    } finally {
        await mongoose.connection.close();
    }
};

export default connect;
```

AddPost.js

```
import mongoose from 'mongoose';

const addNewPostSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    uid: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
    },
    title: {
        type: String,
    },
    content: {
        type: String,
    },
    author: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
    },
}, { timestamps: true });

export default mongoose.models.Posts || mongoose.model("Posts", addNewPostSchema);
```

addpost/page.js

```
'use client'
import { saveData } from "./managePostData"

export default function CreatePost() {
    const handleFormSubmit = async (e) => {
        e.preventDefault()
        const title = e.target[0].value
        const content = e.target[1].value
        const author = e.target[2].value
        let res = saveData(title, content, author)
    }
    return (
        <form className="text-gray-400 bg-gray-900 body-font my-12" onSubmit={handleFormSubmit}>
            <div className="py-6 bg-gray-800 bg-opacity-50 rounded-lg p-8 flex flex-col md:ml-auto w-full mt-10 md:mt-0">
                <h2 className="text-white text-lg font-medium title-font mb-5 text-center">New Post</h2>
                <div className="relative mb-4">
                    <label htmlFor="post-topic" className="leading-7 text-sm text-gray-400">Topic</label>
                    <input type="text" id="post-topic" name="post-topic" className="w-full bg-gray-600 bg-opacity-20 focus:bg-transparent focus:ring-2 focus:ring-indigo-900 rounded border border-gray-600 focus:border-indigo-500 text-base outline-none text-gray-100 py-1 px-3 leading-8 transition-colors duration-200 ease-in-out" />
                </div>
                <div className="relative mb-4">
                    <label htmlFor="post-description" className="leading-7 text-sm text-gray-400">Description</label>
                    <textarea id="post-description" name="post-description" className="w-full bg-gray-600 bg-opacity-20 focus:bg-transparent focus:ring-2 focus:ring-indigo-900 rounded border border-gray-600 focus:border-indigo-500 text-base outline-none text-gray-100 py-1 px-3 leading-8 transition-colors duration-200 ease-in-out" />
                </div>
                <div className="relative mb-4">
                    <label htmlFor="post-author" className="leading-7 text-sm text-gray-400">Author</label>
                    <input type="text" id="post-author" name="post-author" className="w-full bg-gray-600 bg-opacity-20 focus:bg-transparent focus:ring-2 focus:ring-indigo-900 rounded border border-gray-600 focus:border-indigo-500 text-base outline-none text-gray-100 py-1 px-3 leading-8 transition-colors duration-200 ease-in-out" />
                </div>
                <button type="submit" className="text-white bg-indigo-500 border-0 py-2 px-8 focus:outline-none hover:bg-indigo-600 rounded text-lg">Post</button>
            </div>
        </form>
    );
}
```

addpost/managepostdata.js

```
'use server'
// import connect from "@/app/lib/mongodb"
import AddPostModel from "@/app/models/AddPost"

const saveData = async (title, content, author) => {
    let newaddpostobj = new AddPostModel({
        uid: Date.now().toString(36),
        title: title,
        content: content,
        author: author,
    })
    let res = await newaddpostobj.save()
    return res.id.toString()
}

const getData = async () => {
    let res = await AddPostModel.find()
    // console.log(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(res)))
    return JSON.stringify(res)
}

export { saveData, getData }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Timeouts will often happen if a connection hasn't been made. Have you confirmed that a connection has been established. I see the connect function but i don't see it being called anywhere.